# Bash if failed return to previous command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that mounts a windows share and I worked on it to learn bash scripting.

The problem I am facing is that there is a result written in zenity as once the share is mounted it gives out **OK** when it fails to mount it gives out **FAIL**.

Now I want to ask user his password one more time if the output was **FAIL** so if she/he had a mistake in the password she/he can rewrite it.

**Input**

```
## define a function that launched the zenity username dialog
get_password(){
    zenity --entry --width=300 --title="Mount $MOUNTDIR" --text="Password:" --hide-text
}

# attempt to get the password and exit if cancel was pressed
wPassword=$(get_password) || exit

# if the username is empty or matches only whitespace.
while [ "$(expr match "$wPassword" '.')" -lt "1" ]; do
    zenity --error --title="Error in password!" --text="Please check your password! Password field can not be empty!" || exit
    wPassword=$(get_password) || exit
done
```

**Output:**

```
# show if mounting was OK or failed
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        zenity --info --title="Mounting public share succeeded!" --text="Location Documents/Shares/public!"
else
        zenity --error --title="Mounting public did not succeed!" --text="Please contact system administrator!"
fi
```

So I need the script to rerun **input** if output was a **fail**. I hope you understand what I need.

Comment: You need a `while` loop, and `break` upon success

Comment: Can you explain with a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're after is something like:

```
while wPassword=$(get_password)
do
    if mount …options for mount…
    then
        zenity --info --title="Mounting public share succeeded!" \
               --text="Location Documents/Shares/public!"
        break
    else
        zenity --error --title="Mounting public did not succeed!" \
               --text="Please contact system administrator!"
    fi
done
```

This runs the `get_password` function and saves the output; if the `get_password` function returns with a non-zero status, the loop will terminate.  In the body of the loop, it runs the `mount` command and if that succeeds, reports success and breaks the loop.  If it fails, it gives an error message (with a no longer entirely appropriate message), and then goes back to the loop to read a new password.

> … but the problem is that I have save password function in the script and I need that to be started before it gives a success status.

Multiple options are available:

```
while wPassword=$(get_password)
do
    if ! password_saver "$wPassword"
    then break    # Password saver reported error, presumably
    fi
    if mount …options for mount…
    …
```

Or:

```
while wPassword=$(get_password) &&
      password_saver "$wPassword"
do
    if mount …options for mount…
    …
```

If the password saver only indicates an error rather than reporting it, then you'll need to report the problem in your code; that would make the first option better.  You could replace the `break` with `continue` to go around the loop again.  If 'stop loop on password saver error' is correct, then the second is more succinct.

Comment: Yes this works, but the problem is that I have save password function in the script and I need that to be started before it gives a success status. 
Example:
while ....
  then
    save
  after
    give success
  else
    error

Comment: So after the `do` you run the `save` operation and then the `mount`.  It's up to you whether you error check the save status.